How do I speed up querying my >600Mio rows?
My database has about 600Mio entries that I want to query (Pandas is too slow). This local dbSNP only contains rsIDs and genomic positions. I used:
import sqlite3
import gzip
import csv

rsid_db = sqlite3.connect('rsid.db')

rsid_cursor = rsid_db.cursor()

rsid_cursor.execute(
"""
CREATE TABLE rsids (
rsid TEXT,
chrom TEXT,
pos INTEGER,
ref TEXT,
alt TEXT
)
"""
)

with gzip.open('00-All.vcf.gz', 'rt') as vcf: # from https://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/snp/organisms/human_9606/VCF/00-All.vcf.gz
    reader = csv.reader(vcf, delimiter="\t")
    i = 0
    for row in reader:
        if not ''.join(row).startswith('#'):
            rsid_cursor.execute(
            f"""
            INSERT INTO rsids (rsid, chrom, pos, ref, alt)
            VALUES ('{row[2]}', '{row[0]}', '{row[1]}', '{row[3]}', '{row[4]}');
            """
            )
            i += 1
            if i % 1000000 == 0:
                print(f'{i} entries written')
                rsid_db.commit()

rsid_db.commit()

rsid_db.close()

I want to query multiple rsIDs and get their genomic position and alteration (query rsid and get chrom, pos, ref, alt and rsid). One entry looks like:



rsid
chrom
pos
ref
alt




rs537152180
1
4002401
G
A,C



I query using:
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd


def query_rsid(rsid_list,
               rsid_db_path='rsid.db'):

    with sqlite3.connect(rsid_db_path) as rsid_db:

        rsid_cursor = rsid_db.cursor()
        rsid_cursor.execute(
        f"""
        SELECT * FROM rsids
        WHERE rsid IN ('{"', '".join(rsid_list)}');
        """
        )

        query = rsid_cursor.fetchall()

    return query

It takes about 1.5 minutes no matter how many entries. Is there a way to speed this up?

if you only want the Id and genomic position why are you using a SELECT *? Why selecting all fields?

Assuming that 600Mio means 600 million rows I can't help thinking that SQLite may not be the ideal database. Also, how many values are there in rsid_list? As @KlausD. has suggested, an index on the rsid column will probably help

@KlausD.: WOuld an index also help, if the rsid is completely unsorted or would the index also kinda deal with internal sorting?

@Cincinnatus: I SELECT *, because I need the rsid column for merging later.

@SIGHUP: Exactly, 600rows. For the rsid_list, I tested 1, 3 and 6. All took similar times. In the end a real use case would be about up to multiple hundreds.

then why not SELECT rsid FROM ...?

@Cincinnatus: Why should I only select rsid, if I also need the other columns?

Because in the previous comment you said: "I SELECT *, because I need the rsid column". Which implies that you only need rsid. Otherwise you would have said: "I use SELECT * because I need all the columns"

I need the rsid for merging and the others, because this is the info I want (position and alteration).

A properly indexed SQLite database should be fine with this. Tangentially, you might want try DuckDB though; it should be able to ingest that gzipped TSV directly.

@gernophil you should ask exactly what you want. We can't guess what you're trying to do.  Queries and sorting are accelerated by indexes, so if you want to search by rsid you have to create an index. If rsid is the key, it should be created as rsid TEXT PRIMARY KEY. This will generate an index and ensure the rows are unique. Different queries require different indexes though, so beyond the primary key, you need to create indexes that help with your specific queries (which we don't know, so we can't guess)

The alt column may be a problem. SQLite doesn't have array types, so this is just a string. Indexes help with exact, range (ie > or between) or prefix matches. No index can accelerate alt LIKE '%,C.

@PanagiotisKanavos: That's exactly why I wrote: "All I want to do with this db is query multiple rsIDs and get their genomic position (and alteration)". Maybe I should clarify this more: I want to only query rsid(s) and get their chrom, pos, ref, alt. I am currently building the db anew with rsid TEXT PRIMARY KEY. That seems to take much longer now, which is a good sign I guess :D.

What does "Mio" stand for?

1,000,000 (million)

Given a table containing 600 million rows with the rsid column as its primary key, I select 6 rows at random (using sqlite3 built-in RANDOM() function). I then query the table where the IN list has the 6 randomly selected keys and it takes 0.0037s to execute (Python 3.12.6, macOS 15.0)

Others have suggested defining your rsid column as the primary key, or alternatively creating a unique index on it. That's a good idea.
Another thing:  rsid IN ('dirty','great','list','of',items') may use a so-called skip-scan to get its results.  If your rsid_list is very large, or if it pulls in values that are lexically widely separated, you may get a benefit from putting the items in the list into a temporary table then doing
SELECT rsids.*
  FROM rsids
  JOIN temp_rsids_list ON rsids.rsid = temp_rsids_list.rsids

to get a more efficient lookup.
I would declare the table like this:
CREATE TABLE rsids (
  rsid TEXT PRIMARY KEY COLLATE BINARY,
  chrom TEXT,
  pos INTEGER,
  ref TEXT,
  alt TEXT
) WITHOUT ROWID

COLLATE BINARY is the default. But still, it's helpful to show it because you know upfront you don't want case-insensitive matching on that column. This will remind your future self and your colleagues of that important optimization.
WITHOUT ROWID tells SQLite to organize the table as a so-called "clustered index" where the other values are stored along with the easily searchable primary key.
If you can make your primary key into an INTEGER that is a good idea for the sake of performance.

You can create an index on the rsID column:
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_rsid
ON rsids(rsid);

Keyword UNIQUE can only be used if values of rsid are unique. As you stated rsid is your primary key so it is unique by definition.
